# Moving items from list to list?

Tags: c#, list, datagridview, move

I have two DataGridViews labeled: `choiceDGV` and `universalDGV` that are bound to binding sources labeled: `choiceLineBindingSource` and `universalLineBindingSource`.

```
SortableBindingList<ChoiceLine> theChoiceList = new SortableBindingList<ChoiceLine>();
SortableBindingList<UniversalLine> theUniversalList = new SortableBindingList<UniversalLine>();
```

I then add to each list using a `foreach` loops that iterates this:

```
theChoiceList.Add(new ChoiceLine(item1, item2, item3, item4, item5, item6, item7, 
                                 item8, item9, item10, item11, item12, item13));

theUniversalList.Add(new UniversalList(stuff1, stuff2, stuff3, stuff4, stuff5, stuff6, stuff7, 
                                       stuff8, stuff9, stuff10, stuff11, stuff12, stuff13));
```

**Now I call:** `choiceSort();` annd `universalSort();`. They look like this:

```
private void choiceSort()
{
    var sortedChoice = theChoiceList.OrderBy(l => l.Speed);
    choiceLineBindingSource.DataSource = sortedChoice;
}

private void universalSort()
{
    var sortedUniversal = theUniversalList.OrderBy(l => l.Type);
    universalLineBindingSource.DataSource = sortedUniversal;
}
```

### **EDIT:**

Here is the code for the moving of the items.

```
private void toUniversalButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in choiceDGV.SelectedRows)
    {
        object[] items = new object[row.Cells.Count];
        for (int i = 0; i < row.cells.Count; i++)
            items[i] = row.Cells[i].Value;

        theUniversalList.Add(new UniversalList(item1, item2, item3, item4, item5, item6, item7
                                               item8, item9, item10, item11, item12, item13));
        universalSort();

        choiceDGV.Rows.Remove(row);
    }
}
```

---

### **My Problem:**

I also have multiple buttons that move the item from one DGV to another. So on the click, the selected item(s) from `choiceDGV` will be removed and added to `unversalDGV`. However, when I go to move the item(s) back using the other button that removes the item(s) from `universalDGV` and adds to `choiceDGV` I get duplicate items.

If this process is continued and I move the item(s) back-and-fourth **4 times**, I will get that particular item(s) **4 times** instead of just the one that I wanted.

So pretty much I get duplicates. Does anyone know what is going on and how I can fix it so I only get one item when I move back-and-fourth?

### EDIT -- More info on the problem

I just moved every item from one list to the other so that one of the DGV's was completely visibly empty. Now when I click the button to move an item(s) from the other DGV to the visibly empty DGV it repopulates what the DGV had (before it was cleared) **plus (+)** the item(s) that were selected when the move button was clicked...

Comment: The code you have problem with is the only one you haven't provided here, namely the code that (supposedly) moves an item from one list to another. Without this code, it's impossible to help you.

Comment: @theNoobGuy - You've added the wrong code under 'Edit'. We need the code that moves *from* Universal, not *to*.

Comment: @arviman: It is the same code just change everything that contains `choice` with `universal` and same with the other way around..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never seem to remove the original item from theChoiceList, you need to do this at the same time you remove it from choiceDGV (choiceDGV.Rows.Remove(row)) otherwise each time you re-sort it will do it based on theChoiceList which still contains the original item plus the new one.

Comment: Well I thought the binding list would do that.. but I was confused :-/. haha. How exactly would you do this? I tried `theChoiceList.Remove(row);` but it gives me the **error:** `The best overloaded method match for 'System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection<LineBalancer.Universal1Line>.Remove(LineBalancer.Universal1Line)' has some invalid arguments`

Comment: You would do something like `theChoiceList.Remove(theChoiceList.Single(x=>x.item1 == items[0])`. You would have to change this depending on which column is the key.

Comment: @arviman: thanks that works! if you post that as the answer I will accept it.

Comment: to be fair, i was just elaborating what DoctorMick wrote ;) You should mark this the answer.